# Refer a typescript file outside of project directory

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a Web App And Mobile App(Ionic 2) Which is currently in this folder structure

```
Mobile app
  node_modules
  Src
Web app
  node_modules
  Src
```

Since both mobile and web app use the same api for the http calls i created a new folder called shared and placed the API Services and referred them in my Mobile app.Like This

```
Mobile app
  node_modules
  Src
Web app
  node_modules
  Src
Shared
  Services
     LoginService.ts
```

Since my login service has `import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';` and `import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';` .I get the following error when i load my app `Cannot find module '@angular/core'.`

Can Somebody please tell me is it possible to use shared api services in my ionic2 app which is outside of the project directory.Thank You

Comment: you should be creating your calls as a module which can then be imported by both projects

Comment: So i should place all my http services in a module and import the module in app.module of Mobile and WebApp? Ok I wil try it and get back to you

Comment: Yeah so the service calls are then its own isolated code pack which can be imported into any app. So instead of having an outside folder you import a structured module into both projects

Comment: I Created Module and named it as CoreModule then imported it in my app.module.But still i get the same error about `Cannot find module '@angular/core'.` Should i have package.json for shared module and install its dependencies?

Comment: No i dont think so but your new Module and both apps should have `@angular/core` installed

Comment: In both projects i have angular dependencies installed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145934/discussion-between-abhilash-reddy-and-gerdi).